# Can the Taylor shift of a hypergeometric function always be expressed as a nontrivial transformation of another hypergeometric function?

Tags: hypergeometric-functions

Given a function $F(z)$, the function $F(z-m)$ is called
the Taylor shift of $F(z)$.
 If $F(z)$ is a (general) hypergeometric
function, is $F(z-m)$ some simple transformation of a hypergeometric
function?
  Typical transforms of $F(z)$ are $A(z) F(B(z))$
where $A(z), B(z)$ are polynomials.

More precisely, suppose
$F(z)={}_pF_q((a);(b);z)$ where $(a),(b)$ are the parameters,
is $F(z-m)$ is some simple transformation
of another hypergeometric function.  But the Taylor
shift is already in this form: choose $A(z)=1, B(z)=x-m$.
Call this the trivial transformation.  My question is whether non-trivial transformations always exist.

For example, $F(z)={}_1F_0(a;;z)$, I can show the non-trivial transformation,
$$
F(z-m) = (1+m)^{-a} F\big(\frac{z}{1+m}\big)
$$

But does the Taylor shift of $F(z)={}_0F_1(;b;z)$ have a nontrivial transformation?

Taylor shift is very important for efficient algorithms.
Also, any pointers or references would be appreciated.
This is my first question in mathoverflow.  Thanks to the editor who fixed my latex (removing indents).

Comment: You get the LaTeX to process by not indenting.

Comment: $F(z-m)$ is evidently equal to the "simple transform" of $F$, namely $A(z)F(B(z))$, where $A=1$ and $B(z)=z-m$  are polynomials. So what are you asking about?

Comment: Perhaps the question can be phrased as “is there always a non trivial transformation” equivalent to the Taylor shift

Comment: Thanks for the latex Hint about not indenting. (I was copying and pasting my question).

Comment: Alexandre, Thanks for pointing out that original question was self-answering in a trivial way.  It is not clear what I wanted in the final form.

Comment: Thanks, Sidharth.  Reformulated my question as you suggested.